# Histograms exam question

Tags: statistics

[image]

What I did:

$\frac{123}{2} = 62$ median but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Ok so for the median: Calculate the area of each rectangle and find a point $w$ on the $x$-axis such that the total area left of $w$ equals the total area right of $w$. In this image I would say that $w\approx12$.

Answer (score 1):

The median value is the middle value of weights (in tons) that splits all weights data equally, that is $50\%$ from the smallest.

Labeling the height of the bar $0$-$2.5$ by $x$, the total area of all bars must be $1$:
$$2.5\cdot x+2.5\cdot 2x+5\cdot 2.5x+2.5\cdot 3x+2.5\cdot 4x+5\cdot 3.2x+10\cdot 0.8x=1 \Rightarrow \\
61.5x=1 \Rightarrow \frac{61.5x}{2}=\frac12 \Rightarrow 30.75x=0.5$$
Now we find the half area:
$$2.5x+5x+12.5x+7.5x+0.8125\cdot 4x=30.75x$$
Hence, the median is: $12.5+0.8125=13.3125.$